# Android: DeadObjectException for InputMethodService (SoftKeyboard API sample)

Tags: java, android, exception, keyboard

I'm playing around with a modified version of the SoftKeyboard sample and "sometimes" get a `DeadObjectException` when using the fullscreen mode (e.g. when orientation == landscape). I can still enter text, but the `ExtractEditText` doesn't update and I get the logcat output below, whenever I hit a new key.

When I switch to portrait (no fullscreen mode) I can see the entered characters. When I then go back to landscape (fullscreen mode) the `ExtractEditText` is updated with the characters. However, when I then try to enter new character the problem repeats.

Also, when in fullscreen mode and I change the cursor position it does change it in the `ExtractEditText` but doesn't really change the position for my `InputConnection`. I believe this problem/bug is already in the SoftKeyboard API sample, since I didn't modify anything related to that, however, so far I wasn't able to figure out where.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

```
13349     InputMethodManager  W  IME died: com.playground.keyboard/.MyInputMethod
13349     InputMethodManager  W  android.os.DeadObjectException
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.updateSelection(IInputMethodSession.java:227)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.updateSelection(InputMethodManager.java:1190)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4064)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6591)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6697)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6594)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6594)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6594)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
13349     InputMethodManager  W     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you resolved it? Can u please give me some hint? I am facing this issue each time when keyboard shows.